# Вопрос по оптимизации HTTP сервера

Tags: node.js, http, оптимизация, request, минификация

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой из предложенных сценариев будет работать быстрее?

1. После запроса на сайт - юзеру передаются с сервера отдельно по одному файлу html, css, js;
2. После запроса на сайт - юзеру передаётся с сервера один html, один css, и уже затем асинхронно вызываются необходимые js скрипты;
3. После запроса на сайт - юзеру передаются с сервера все html, css, js маленькими кусочками;
4. После запроса на сайт - юзеру передаётся один html файл в котором уже содержатся все css, js и дополнительно делать запросы к ним не нужно.

Вопрос задаю т.к. натыкался на статьи одних, где говориться, что лучше много маленьких запросов, чем один большой, а так-же на статьи других, где говориться, что чем меньше запросов - тем быстрее! Так что из этого всё же правда?

Answer (score 1):

1. Первое и самое важное - минимизировать код
2. Проанализировать ситуацию: сколько у вас css файлов? Если у вас есть main.css и пару дополнительных .css которые индивидуальны для других страниц, то оцените, как часто на них заходят. Если их посещают часто, то объедините их в main.css и не гоняйте диски сервера просто так. (Если main.css весит 40кб а доп. файлы к нему будут по 2-5кб, то подумайте сами, в 2019 кто из-за 5 дополнительных кб будет париться? А вот сервера будет немного легче)
3. Аналогично с .js

Отправка каждого файла с сервера это целый запрос на сервер, который ему надо обработать. А теперь представьте, что у вас большой объем запросов в секунду?

А еще лучше попробуйте устроить нагрузочное тестирование с замером производительности, и тогда вы точно узнаете, какой способ в вашем случае наилучший.

Comment: «Отправка каждого файла с сервера это целый запрос на сервер» — в случае с HTTP/2 это не всегда так, да и в случае HTTP/1.1 очень помогают параллельные запросы и pipelining

Comment: В моём приложении к сожалению важен каждый КБ.